# How to I prevent this proxy login box?

Tags: macos, monterey, proxy

Whenever I connect to our organisations VPN, every app that uses the Internet pops up with this box asking me to log into the proxy.

[image: Sign in: The proxy at URL requires a username and password]

I do not need to provide a username or password, so each time I just click "Sign In" and it works. While it is only a minor inconvenience, it is a frequent one, so is getting somewhat irritating.

I am on a MacBook Pro on macOS 12.5.1.

Is there any way to prevent this system wide?

Comment: The box shown is not a system prompt, looks like it's Firefox or Chrome. Does the system one have a checkbox to remember your password?

Comment: This particular one is in Chrome, yes, but as far as my research can tell it is a system prompt as opposed to a browser prompt. No, none of the same from other apps have a "remember password" option

Comment: If the other ones don't have a checkbox, then it's inconsequential. But this specific one is a Chrome alert. Unfortunately I don't have anything else to offer here, best of luck